# Hibernate LAZY fetch

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have problem with Hibernate and LAZY fetch. I have Spring+Hibernate app. When I use EAGER fetch it is OK, but when I change fetch to LAZY it throws `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`

**Model**

ParentRequest

```
   import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity(name = "PARENT_REQUEST")
    @Table(name = "PARENT_REQUEST")
    public class ParentRequest implements Serializable{

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="parent_id",nullable = false)
        private Parent parent;

        public ParentRequest() {
        }
//getter setters..
}
```

Parent

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet;

@Entity(name = "PARENT")
@DiscriminatorValue("par")
public class Parent extends User {

    public final static String ROLE_NAME = "par";

    //private Set<Student> students;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<ParentRequest> parentRequests = new HashSet();

    public Parent() {
    }

//getters, setters
}
```

**Hibernate config in springContext.xml**

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>model.ParentRequest</value>
                <value>model.Parent</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

dataSource bean is configured well.

**Here is stack trace of JUnit test:**

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Parent.parentRequests, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:162)
    at dao.impl.UserHibernateDAOTest.testSetParentReq_Parent(UserHibernateDAOTest.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

I use Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE and Hibernate 3.6.10.Final.

Thanks!

Comment: All your posted code is working fine. The relavant part ist the business code where you do operation on these entities. Make sure that these operations on the parent and parentrequest happen within a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You are tryng to access lazy collection after session is closed. Read [this](http://tech.lalitbhatt.net/2014/07/hibernate-persistent-context-and-session.html). YOu can get the collection when the object accessed the first time or keep the session

Update: Also you can check [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/four-solutions-to-lazyinitializationexc_05.html)